# Buttons and Labels not placing properly on frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am really new to coding and python and this could be just a lack of basic knowledge, but every time I run the code it displays the `Button`s and `Label`s in the default top left position. Does anyone know where the mistake is or how to fix this issue?

I initially tried this with `.grid(row = 1, column = 5)` but this also didn't work.

```
def swap(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

for frame in (f1, f2, f3):
    frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

# ---------------------------------------1
# This is just the first frame but I think this is scaleable

name1 = Label(f1, text = "Frame 1")
name1.pack(side = BOTTOM)

switchbutton1 = Button(f1, text = "Next Frame", command = lambda: swap(f2))
switchbutton1.pack(side = BOTTOM)
```

I don't get any error message but it only displays in the default position.
I expect that I can put the buttons with `.grid()` or `.pack()` in a custom position.

Comment: empty rows/columns have no size. You would have to put elements in other rows/column to move item in `.grid(row = 1, column = 5)`.

Comment: Or use ie. `frame.grid_columnconfigure(column_number, minsize=10)` to set minimal size for column and then you see this column even if it is empty.

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve], but as a general rule you should not mix grid() and pack() calls within the same frame (or root) widget. Those methods are for using two different `tkinter` geometry managers that don't play well together. Here's some slightly outdated [documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20190524140835id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) that may help.

Comment: You can use ```.place``` instead.

Comment: As you put all the frames inside same cell and there is no other widget in other cell, the frame will be shown in top-left no matters what `row` and `column` are assigned.